# Ruby on Rails model/controller access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models, *subject* and *page*. I created a one-to-many association between them.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :position
  attr_accessible :visible
  attr_accessible :created_at
end
```

and

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject

  attr_accessible :subject_id
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :permalink
  attr_accessible :position
  attr_accessible :visible
  attr_accessible :created_at
end
```

As mentioned above, I have two models, and I want to access all subject names which are in the Subject model to the page model/controller...

Comment: not an answer, but you can declare multiple attributes in a single `attr_accessible` call to dry your code up a bit.

Comment: Just a hunch but you might want to check out the acts_as_api gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all the subjects saved in a subject model use:

```
Subject.pluck(:name)
```

or to access a subjects associated with particular page:

```
page = Page.first
page.subject  #subject object associated with the page
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Subject.select("subjects.name").joins(:pages).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you can access subject's pages or page's subject.

```
s = Subject.create(<params>)
s.pages  # array of page objects

p = Page.create(<params>)
p.subject # subject object
```

Comment: Don't you mean `.where(<params>)` instead of `.create(<params>)`?